# How the check for update works in background in every application

Tags: python, deployment, background, key, registry

i need to know, how the check for update works in the system. That is , while clicking the check for update how the application interact with the application server.

The application changes anything in the application. That is any registry value changes in background.

Comment: *.. how the application  interact with the application server*.. hmm.. which application? System update manager or what?

Comment: i need a common solution. Iam not mention any application name. There may be a any application. every application have a check for update. if we chick check for update the is some background process is going. i need to know, what is that background process.

Comment: so, I think there is no common solution to cover all applications because an app and its server can communicate with their own way (server can be local or remote, it can works as another host or like another process or service, if the server is remote it can work as HTTP server, TCP/IP server or it can work with its own protocol with specific encryption or without..). Anyway you have to know what you work with.